# My Macbook falls asleep everytime that I pick it up?

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake

If my MacBook is sitting on the desk and I go and pick it up, it will fall asleep and will not wake up regardless of pressing space bar or pressing the power button. Literally the only way I can get it to work is by shaking the macbook (I then hear a soft single beep) and then I place it back on the desk and then hit the laptop lightly against the desk and it will wake up. What is the problem and is there anyway I could fix it. (I feel like the beeping noise might mean something when it is in sleep mode?)

Anyways my Macbook is a late 2011 Macbook Pro and it is on 10.7.5. Thanks

Comment: @jadav This and a couple of other comments are not constructive. Try to keep comments to honest efforts to help move the discussion forward. Unrelated comments and also ones that basically tell the asker they are wrong are often flagged as not constructive and I'd rather not have you get locked out of commenting due to excessive flag for unhelpful comments.

Comment: OK, I thought they were constructive trying to get the question has been revised. Like the one who does not like the Safari show all bookmarks ? What is the purpose of that question?

Comment: @Jadav Thanks for the ping here. Let's move the discussion to http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8103/discussions-with-jadav Just request access and we can chat directly without cluttering this question here with off topic comments.

Comment: well I tried to log in but it won't let me

Comment: Here is the reason ? Storage – failed

Your browser either does not support localStorage, or it is disabled for stackauth.com. Either upgrade your browser, or enable localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it might need repairs; there could be a loose ribbon cable inside that's disconnecting when you move it.

That said, the whole scenario sounds mysteriously uncommon.